# ag-grid + angularJS header and cells editable by the user

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I just start using the `ag-grid` library with `angularJS` to display some tabular data in my application. The thing now is that I want the user to be able to alter the header value of each column like as he/she can edit the cells within a column when we enable the `editable` attribute. While searching for a solution I realized that there is no default way to turn the header into an editable element. So I was wondering which are my alternatives.

One thought of mine was to add to each header an edit button and when clicked a modal window to pop up with the corresponding input fields of the header and its column's cell values. In this case, the `editable` attribute is not going to be used because the edit of the cells will be conducted within the modal. Something like [that](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*hYe908S3w_USPbss) but instead for the row, the button should be in each header.

So which are the ways that I can achieve something like that? I read about [header template](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/) but couldn't really found any straightforward way to approach it.

Any ideas/hints or other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Header - just a name of the field in data-object which is passed by you via `rowData` or `setData`.
For what you need to modify a header? should it change the structure then?

Comment: I want, the user to be able to change the structure. Let's say for example that each row describes a linear model. The first column describes the first parameter, the second column the second parameter etc. So I want the user to be able to set the name of that parameter as well as the value of it for each model.

Comment: have you thought about how you will update the structure inside ag-grid?
I mean, ok, the case is clear for now, but you wanna to combine it in one `component` and actually I don't think its good idea.

Comment: No. I didn't thought it and that's why I asked here. Maybe there was something that I missed from the documentation. Combine what with a component? How do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Make a service which have an array as DataSet of your grid, and provide it with handlers for the events of a CRUD in the same service. Inject the service into the controller of your modal and view of the grid. After that, call the object gridDataSetadd,remove,update who is in the service, then $digest do the rest of the work once DataSet will be modified.

**UPDATE, answering the comment**

Inject your service into your controller:

For .ts

```
static $inject = ['$scope','YourService'];
constructor($scope, userService: YourService) {
    this.userService.getSomething();
}
```

For .js

```
.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', 'YourService', function ($scope, YourService) {
    $scope.someVar = YourService.someVar;
}])
```

Comment: Excuse, but how am I going to inject the service to the view of the grid? Can you give me an example?